# Eclipse SQL-Java testing environment

Tags: java, sql

I'm not sure what is would be called but I was wondering if there was some sort of eclipse plugin that I could install that would allow me to run a simulated SQL database in the IDE as I run my Java code also on the IDE?

Comment: Please can you update the question with some info: 1. Are you using a build tool like Maven to run your code, or are you just using Run as Java application in Eclipse? 2. How is your database connection configured? Please show the snippet of code, or Spring config etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a plugin to do this, there are several pure Java databases that you can use, that are commonly used for local dev and or testing. e.g. I've used both HSQLDB and H2:

http://hsqldb.org/

http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: Or `Java DB` (formerly Apache Derby) which is even included in the JDK.